# How to get all windows and popups in android application?

Tags: android, popup, window, popupwindow

My understanding is that a single android application can have multiple windows and multiple popups showing at the same time from one activity. When this happens, how can we determine the number of windows and popups and get a handle to them? For example, if a user clicks on the overflow icon then the popup will show; but, since this popup isn't under the rootview I can't call rootView.findViewById(R.id.actionbarPopup) (for example). How would i get the handle to that popup?

Comment: What you can do is, keep all the active alerts in a single list, and manage them accordingly.

Comment: Why would you need a handle to it?

Comment: First, I expect there's some method that would indicate a dialog/window/popup has been created and would like to know what that trigger is so I can listen for it and react to it. There are different reasons for listening, just like listening for a view being attached to root has many reasons. Secondly, I want a handle to any menus/popups created by the actionbar in order to style them. Before telling me to use styles.xml for that purpose, try to set the background to a tiled and colorized drawable or try to make the popup's width wrap its children...not possible using a style/theme (right?)